# Prevent "hijacking" the intention of a link click when applying custom functionality to a click event

Tags: javascript, usability

For example, there is some JavaScript code which has a click handler which determines where the user should be redirected to. Let's say it's just a redirection random link that is calculated when the user clicks the link.

Here are some scenarios:

- If the user left clicks on the link, the intention of the user is to keep the navigation in the same tab, which works fine with `window.location`.
- If the user middle clicks this link, to the user it appears that the website has hijacked the middle click and simply ignored it, redirecting the user within the same tab instead of a new tab.
- Also, as someone just commented (and deleted the comment?), another scenario is modifier keys can also suggest to the browser to open a new tab, or even a new window.
- Another suggestion is being able to open a link in a new tab or window via the context menu. This is less important, but definitely the same usability issue.

I've seen this issue on many websites, notably for me, Google Analytics, where almost every time I middle click, this effect happens.

A good example of what some JavaScript code needs to is:

> Process some data, then send off a XHR request that needs to be
>   completed before allowing the user to continue to the link they
>   clicked on.

How do you get around this? e.g. are there ways to detect if the user has expected the link to appear in the new tab, and if so, is it possible to load up a new tab? Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way around?

Answer (score 2):

`event.button` can be used to identify which mouse button was clicked.
The Middle button returns 1.

The `event` object also contains the properties `event.ctrlKey`, `event.altKey` and `event.shiftKey` which are self-explanatory. Their values are `true` if the corresponding keys are pressed, and `false` otherwise.

---

The behaviour you wish to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/nCdhv/9/

html:

```
<a id="smart" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/">Click</a>​
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#smart').on('click', function(event) {
        if (event && event.button && event.button === 1) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open($('#smart').attr('href'), '_blank');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});​
```

---

src: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.button
browser support: http://help.dottoro.com/ljaxplfi.php

Comment: Are there any common browsers that do not fire the `click` event when the element has been middle-clicked?

Comment: If you can't provide a URL for the user to go to it might be better to use a blank ('#','javascript:;'.. etc) URL or not use an `<a>` at all. You can detect middle clicks but you can't detect the options in the right click menu (open in new tab/window, copy link ...).

Comment: @Vatev why do you need to detect the options in the right click menu? OP wishes to know how to detect middle clicks.

Comment: @bPratik I'm just pointing out that you cant fully implement a link's behaviour in JS. Otherwise there is nothing wrong in detecting middle clicks and opening new tabs :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but the underlying question. A mate of mine realised that `$.ajax` has a `async: false` option.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({url: '/', async: false}).done(function(d) { alert('hello ' + d) })
    })
})​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gakman/7qdXE/

This will block the `href=""` click event until the ajax response has returned, continuing with whatever tab/window the link was headed.

He also says "this is the worst thing ever" which is absolutely true.

Answer (score 0):

To get consistent behaviour across browsers, set the link's href attribute to an appropriate value *before* the user clicks on it. Then it's up to the user to determine whether the link should be opened in the same window, a new window or a tab.

e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.apple.com" onclick="this.href='http://www.google.com'">Apple</a>
```

In IE 9 and Firefox, left click opens Google, ctrl + left click will open Apple in a new tab, as will right click and selecting "Open link in new tab". The only way to fix that is to set the href before the user clicks on the link.

A click event will likely not be dispatched for either middle or right clicks on links.

If the link has been clicked and the back button is used to return to the page, the link's href may be the original or stay as modified by script.

The bottom line is to let links behave like links. If some other behaviour is required, use buttons or a different UI object.

Comment: Another point of view of my question is when some JavaScript processing and XHR requests need to be completed before allowing the user to continue to the link they clicked on. I'll update the question with this example.

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using links at all. In some browsers, the moment the user clicks on a link scripts stop executing (probably because the browser is about to navigate elsewhere).

Comment: And a solution like this: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527 comes about, which falls back to my original question :)